# python @property not overwrite class attribute

Tags: python, oop

I'm confused with the class attribute. I understand that Python interpreter will search attr inside `cls.__dict_` (object attribute) first, If the attribute doesn't exists, it will looking for at class attributes. But in that case I dont know why the result below return None

```
class A(object):
    __attr = None

    @property
    def attr(self):
        return self.__attr

class B(A):
    __attr = 1

c = B()
print(c.attr)
# None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't about `property`, but about the behaviour of attributes prefixed with `__`. This triggers name mangling, which is almost never what you want and behaves unexpectedly in an inheritance scenario. Don't use it.